# boost score based on whether the value (numeric) of a given field is in a specific range

Tags: solr, solr-boost

I want to boost a record's matching score if its value in field A is greater than a certain number.

For example, if the value in A is greater than 4, I would like to give it a boost of 5. I tried the following for `bf` and `bq` separately, but it did not work.

```
if(A>4,5,0)
```

How should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [FunctionQuery](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Function+Queries). 
With edismax  queryparser,  you need to specify the boost query parameter in the following way:

```
bq=if(A>4,5,1)
```

Comment: thanks, but that is what I used. I am in solr dashboard and specefied `if(A>4,5,1)` in the bq box. I got the following error.
`"error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],
    "msg":"undefined field: \"A\"",
    "code":400}}`

Comment: @user2868104 is `A` the actual name of your field?